# Protecting Java Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

We are making Java adapter, and want to protect by CustomAuthenticator and CustomLoginModule.

We started from sample project got from:
https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/authentication-security/custom-authenticator-login-module/custom-authenticator-login-module-hybrid-applications/

We then added simple Java Adapter.

Then, in the client code, we modified `getSecretData()` function in main.js so that it calls */adapters/JavaAdapter/users* instead of original */adapters/DummyAdapter/getSecretData*.

Finally, We added the `@OAuthSecurity(scope="CustomAuthenticatorRealm")` annotation to the adapter's `hello()` function.

But clicking "call protected adapter proc" button successfully returns the data from `hello()` **without authentication**.

What should we do so that authentication works for Java adapter calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that your client (Browser? Emulator? Device?) Still has a valid session id with your server, from the time you tested with the javascript adapter.

I've tried your scenario and experienced the same thing. However I was able to get the correct behavior by clearing the cookies (for the ios emulator, by resetting the emulator).

It is expected behavior until you log out.
The logout feature is not working correctly with Java Adapters in 7.0.

Comment: Do you know if there is a work-around for logout in java adapters? maybe in 7.1?

Comment: It should work in 7.1. There is a fix planned for 7.0 but no dates yet.

Comment: That is great news! We will upgrade to 7.1 :)

Comment: Thanks. We are using Browser to test desktopbrowser app. I cleared browser cache, and found it work. But as you said, logout does not work. We should consider work-around.

Comment: I tried the same app in 7.1, but still logout doesn't work.

Comment: In 7.1, for the browser preview, try to refresh the page after the logout. Or in the logout function replace reload with reload(). In emulators and devices it should work fine.